# Qimage Saves Low Quality

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, qimage

Hi I have a file picker that takes an image and saves it as a jpg but it looks horrible. Please help I don't know why it looks bad.

```
    def getfile(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',"","Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")
        print(fname)
        img = QImage(fname)

        img = img.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_Indexed8,Qt.ThresholdDither|Qt.AutoColor)
        newname = 'Old/'+ time.strftime("img%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + '.jpg'
        print(newname)
        os.rename('Background.jpg', newname)
        img.save('Background.jpg', "jpg", 100)
```

I have it set to 100 but still it doesn't help

Before[image]

After[image]

The idea is to allow a user to add an image as background but if the image is png or bmp to convert it to jpeg so that it uses the name "Background.jpg"

Comment: Please post some *before* and *after* pictures so that we can see what you mean by "horrible". What are you trying to achieve with the of the `img.convertToFormat` statement? I believe that with those parameters you are converting to an 8 bit-per-pixel image with a color map. If so, it's not surprising that it looks bad.

Comment: I have edited my post and added images. How to I set it to a higher bit-per-pixel?

Comment: This confirms that the new image is 8-bit with a color table. To change it you must set the correct parameters of `convertToFormat`. You probably don't need this line at all; try what happens if you remove it. Otherwise read [its documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#convertToFormat) to understand its parameters.